# Why is my onclick handler called twice/thrice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please see my code, check console and you'll see, when DOUBLE-CLICKING the button, the test function is called twice, sometimes three times! (I've disabled dblclick)...

I need it to be called only once!

https://jsfiddle.net/kx7x0ems/

```
<img onclick="test(1, 2, 3)" src="http://www.kafkabrigade.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/button-pic.jpg" />

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("*").dblclick(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});

function test(a, b, c) {
    console.log('test clicked - ' + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the double function calls by adding a flag variable:

```
var flag = false;

function test(a, b, c) {
    if (!flag) {
        console.log('test clicked - ' + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
        flag = true;
        setTimeout(function(){ flag = false; }, 400);
    }
}
```

The flag will reset after 400ms (change it to whatever you want) so only the first click will count; additional clicks won't be processed until the flag timer resets.

Here is a working example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("*").dblclick(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
});

var flag = false;

function test(a, b, c) {
    if (!flag) {
        console.log('test clicked - ' + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
        flag = true;
        setTimeout(function(){ flag = false; }, 400);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<img onclick="test(1, 2, 3)" src="http://www.kafkabrigade.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/button-pic.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use onclick on the html tag as well, it will trigger it on every single click.

Instead go this route:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("img").one("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    test(1, 2, 3);
  });
});

function test(a, b, c) {
  console.log('test clicked - ' + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://www.kafkabrigade.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/button-pic.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from the fact that you are setting up this double-click event handler on all DOM elements ("*") and events bubble. See **[this](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)** for details on bubbling. Additionally, your image is set up with a `click` event handler, so if you double click on the image, you will trigger both the click and the double-click events.

The solution is to pick a particular element that you want to handle the event. If you want to capture all double-clicks, set up the event on the `document` object like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle - test is still called twice, sometimes 3 times

Comment: See my comment above

Comment: My original question says I want test to be called only ONCE when clicking or double-clicking, but even with your fix, the test is called multiple times...

Comment: Actually, your original question (and the title of your post) is: *"Why is my onclick handler called twice/thrice?"*, which I have answered correctly.

Comment: I think OP's real question is how to "disable double click", he thought stopPropagation() would stop second onclick from firing, but it's already fired before that.

Comment: I understand. But, he's down voting me and arguing because he didn't word and title his own question properly.

Comment: I agree, I up-voted Scott's answer, it answers the question asked in the tile, should not be down-voted.

Comment: Thanks @Canolyb1. Let's remember that SO is a knowledge base and when people search, the title of the question is given large weight. Imagine someone else having the same problem and finding this question. My answer would be the most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery available, you can use the `.one()` method to ensure that an event only gets fired once: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Then you can avoid having to prevent the doubleclick.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("img").one('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        test(1,2,3)
    });
});

function test(a, b, c) {
    console.log('test clicked - ' + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.kafkabrigade.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/button-pic.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use .off()

Here is an example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(document).off().on("dblclick", function(){
});   });
```